# SQL injection in Node Mysql library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to do some sql injection in node mysql library.

I have an Insert query written in Nodejs using by doing:

```
  pool.query(`Insert into orders(orderType,CustomerID,storeNumber,stageNumber) Values('${orderType}',${customerID},'${storeNumber}','${stageNumber}')`,function(err,rows,fields){
     if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        var orderID=rows.insertId
    }
```

All of the varaibles comes form a form which I am receiving using `req.body`

In the stageNumber field in the form instead of the storeNumber I was writing:

```
'); Delete from orderDetail;
```

This did not delete anything from my table

From my console.log(err) i get

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'Delete from orderDetail;')'

I cannot think of a way to remove the `')'` but I know where it is coming from. Is it even possible to do SQL injection in Node MySQL library?

Comment: It won't allow you to execute multiple queries in a single call. You can do SQL injection, but not the kind that creates multiple queries.

Comment: Most MySQL APIs don't allow multiple queries, so Little Bobby Tables can't succeed.

Comment: The only API I know of that allows multiple queries is `mysqli_multi_query()` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried

```
'); Delete from orderDetail; --
```

This will ignore any characters post -- and should ideally work in this case.